# 1D convolution for CNN

Tags: matlab, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

In Keras there is a special function for 1D convolution for CNN:

```
keras.layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, strides=1, padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', dilation_rate=1, activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
```

Is there a way to do the same in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MATLAB version is R2016a or newer, you should be able to use the 2d-conv layer ([`convolution2dLayer`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/nnet.cnn.layer.convolution2dlayer.html)) with a 1x1 `FilterSize` to get a "1d-conv behavior".

You will need to specify the activation function as a separate layer.